# Stream once with multiple independent conditions each having own action or normal for loop

Tags: java, java-stream

Assume I have `List<List<Integer>> lstOfintLst` , where  for each `List<Integer> intList` I have to check multiple conditions and for each condition I have a set of actions ex count of each condition match , adding them in new `List<Integer> matchedLstCon_x` etc.
New to Java 8 , I am not clear how can I achieve it with just streaming once instead had to steam for each conditions as below

```
AtomicInteger count_Unmatched= new AtomicInteger();
AtomicInteger count_Con_1= new AtomicInteger();
AtomicInteger count_Con_2= new AtomicInteger();
AtomicInteger count_Con_3= new AtomicInteger();

List<Integer> list_Unmatched = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> list_Con_1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> list_Con_2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> list_Con_3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

lstOfintLst.stream().forEach(intList -> {
  boolean isUnmatched=true;
   
   if(intList.stream.allMatch(Condition_1)){
             count_Con_1.getAndIncrement();
             isUnmatched = false;
             list_Con_1.add(intList);

    }

   if(intList.stream.allMatch(Condition_2)){
             count_Con_2.getAndIncrement();
             isUnmatched = false;
             list_Con_2.add(intList);

    }

   if(intList.stream.allMatch(Condition_3)){
             count_Con_3.getAndIncrement();
             isUnmatched = false;
             list_Con_3.add(intList);

    }
   
   if(isUnmatched){
             count_Unmatched.getAndIncrement();              
             list_Unmatched.add(intList);

    }

}
    
   // process all counts & lists
```

So here we are streaming 3 times for each condition ,on top of this if for a condition if I have a specific action on the elements of the `intList` I will again have to do a secondary `intList.stream.` inside the condition

Can we do all condition with one stream ? This can be done with one normal `for-loop` on `intList` , irrespective of the number of conditions with may be more variables etc.

If this is the least number of streams then how is it still better `for-loop` ?
How do I decide which way to go?

Edit : old-fashioned way code added with some ex conditions as asked by [@cyberbrain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2846138/cyberbrain)

```
        int count_Unmatched = 0;
        int count_Con_1 = 0;
        int count_Con_2 = 0;
        int count_Con_3 = 0;

        List<List<Integer>> list_Unmatched = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Integer>> list_Con_1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Integer>> list_Con_2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Integer>> list_Con_3 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<Integer> intList : lstOfintLst) {

            boolean isUnmatched = true;
            int sum = 0;
            int countEven = 0;
            int countOdd = 0;
            int countMultipleOf3 = 0;
            int numLstSize = intList.size();
            for (Integer i : intList) {

                //all are odd or even
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    countEven++;
                }
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    countOdd++;
                }

                //all multiples of 3
                if (i % 3 == 0) {
                    countMultipleOf3++;
                }

                // sum of all elements in intList is multiple of 5
                sum = sum + i;


            }

            if (numLstSize == countEven || numLstSize == countOdd) {
                count_Con_1++;
                list_Con_1.add(intList);
                isUnmatched = false;
            }

            if (numLstSize == countMultipleOf3) {
                count_Con_2++;
                list_Con_2.add(intList);
                isUnmatched = false;
            }

            if (sum % 5 == 0) {
                count_Con_3++;
                list_Con_3.add(intList);
                isUnmatched = false;
            }

            if (isUnmatched) {
                count_Unmatched++;
                list_Unmatched.add(intList);

            }


        }


        // process all counts & lists
```

Comment: I think it really depends on the conditions whether you need to stream the inner lists multiple times or not. How would you implement it with "old-fashioned" for-loops? If you can add such an implementation to your question, we might be able to help you with a switch to streams.

Comment: You can `&&` inside your stream also. Like `intList.stream.allMatch(Condition_1) && intList.stream.allMatch(Condition_2) && intList.stream.allMatch(Condition_3)` . You may want to look at `Stream.filter` to achieve what you want

Comment: @SayanBhattacharya If I put && how can I have sperate action for each condition ex getting each condition match count ? also my question is around reducing count of streams

Comment: @2FaceMan Sorry I overlooked the *condition match count* part.  Reducing the stream is doable but with match count, I can't think of anything on top of my head right now.

Comment: @cyberbrain I added the "old-fashioned" for-loops

Answer (score 1):

Well, the code you've provided looks like a bit chaotic self-imposed coding challenge or a part of a project which became unmanageable.

Always think about the use cases and data structures that would be suitable for these use cases. Don't cram everything into a single method, instead try to think how can you spit the functionalities - learn about the [*Single responsibility principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

You've created four lists of lists, what's next? How are you going to work with them, how can you pass around this data - by wrapping with another list? List of lists of lists, doesn't sound nicely.

The key point is that you need to structure your data in a meaningful way.

Here's one of the possible solutions (*disclaimer:* I can't say for sure that it would be the most suitable approach for your project).

These lists can be store in a `Map` as *values*, and *keys* of the *map* would represent matching conditions.

We can introduce an *enum* encapsulating the conditional logic in a form of `Predicate`s. Members of the *enum* would be used as *keys*.

```
public enum MyPredicate {
    IS_EVEN("Is Even", list -> list.stream().allMatch(i -> i % 2 == 0)),
    IS_ODD("Is Odd", list -> list.stream().allMatch(i -> i % 2 != 0)),
    IS_DIVISIBLE_BY_THREE("Is Divisible By Three", list -> list.stream().allMatch(i -> i % 3 == 0)),
    DEFAULT("No Matches", list -> true);
    
    private static final EnumSet<MyPredicate> withoutDefault = EnumSet.range(IS_EVEN, IS_DIVISIBLE_BY_THREE);
    
    private String predicateName;
    private Predicate<List<Integer>> predicate;
    
    MyPredicate(String predicateName, Predicate<List<Integer>> predicate) {
        this.predicateName = predicateName;
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }
    
    public static List<MyPredicate> getMatches(List<Integer> list) {
        List<MyPredicate> matchingEnums = withoutDefault.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.predicate.test(list))
            .toList();
        
        return matchingEnums.isEmpty() ? List.of(DEFAULT) : matchingEnums;
    }
    
    public boolean matches(List<Integer> list) {
        return predicate.test(list);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return predicateName;
    }
}
```

The process of creating these resulting lists boils down to finding the matching predicate for every list in the input and mapping the list to a matching predicate.

***Note:** that I've ignored all the counters that you've used in code for a reason. Such logic is absolutely not viable with streams, you should not change the state functions in the stream should not use side effects and accumulate the stated outside the stream. And even with loops, these counters are redundant if you need all elements in a list to match a particular condition.*

That's how it might be implemented using [`Stream.collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)):

```
public static Map<MyPredicate, List<List<Integer>>> splitIntoGroups(List<List<Integer>> lists) {
    return lists.stream()
        .collect(
            HashMap::new,
            (Map<MyPredicate, List<List<Integer>>> map, List<Integer> list) ->
                MyPredicate.getMatches(list).forEach(p -> {
                    if (p.matches(list)) map.computeIfAbsent(p, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(list);
                }),
            (left, right) -> right.forEach((key, v) ->
                left.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).addAll(v))
        );
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> sourceList = List.of(
        List.of(1, 2, 3), List.of(4, 6, 8), List.of(5, 7, 9), List.of(3, 9, 18)
    );
    
    splitIntoGroups(sourceList).forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
}
```

*Output:*

```
Is Divisible By Three -> [[3, 9, 18]]
Is Even -> [[4, 6, 8]]
Is Odd -> [[5, 7, 9]]
No Matches -> [[1, 2, 3]]
```